# Where do I find list of Graph API end-points?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Perhaps it's lame question but I can't find the obvious.

Where do I find list of Graph API end-points and documentation on them ? I'm referring to endpoints such as `https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins` and etc.

I don't see it **[here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try "User"/"Connections" section:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

For example, for checkins it will be  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#checkins